# Url rewritting does not render images and file with .js extension

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am using an `apache server`  to run my local website .Below I have rewriten the url in my local `.htaccess` file so that any request not found is redirected to `index.php` file . But  I don' t understand why  certain file like `images  or js files` are not loaded successfuly in my website .Since there are supposed to be found and rendered. The index.php file  is like `router` that reads url and deal with requests accordingly . Everyhing works properly apart from certain file (expecially `images` and file with `.js` as extension ) which I don' t know why there not rendered . Below is the rule I wrote in .htaccess .
It is like these files are not found whereas they exist  . When I inspect no error is reported and all return with number `200 as status code`

**NB : All files not rendered exist in my folder .More I can access them directly if I remove the rule**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have an extra `%` - it should be just `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` not `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}%` See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: @IMSoP YOU ARE RIGHT AND THANKS FOR THE RESSOURCE. MY SERVER IS NOW WORKING AS EXPECTED